# Single word, or phrase of two or three words, for "regular customer"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there an English single term for a *regular customer* who, because of always buying from the same seller, acquires a discount from the seller and might also treat their relationship as that of being a friend?

In our language (*Filipino*), the seller calls a regular customer [a] *"suki"*.

*Patron* sounds like a supporter of a cause, and *habitué* doesn't have the connotation of friendship. Is there a more suitable term for it in English?

Comment: Some people just shorten to 'regular':
"Norm was a regular at Cheer's." Also, one can say 'loyal customer' or 'preferred customer' (but the last one use more for marketing loyalty incentives *to* customers).

Comment: @Merk I think your comment is an answer.

Comment: 'Loyal customer' is probably the one carrying the biggest hint of comradeship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[***pa·tron***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/patron)
2. A customer, especially a regular customer.
[The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition copyright ©2000]

***patron***
2. (Business / Commerce) a customer of a shop, hotel, etc., esp a regular one
[Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged © HarperCollins]

[Patronage -Commercial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patronage#Commercial) (Wikipedia)
Sometimes consumers support smaller or local businesses or corporations out of loyalty even if less expensive options exist. Their regular custom is referred to as 'patronage'.